# Jquery AJAX not formatting or reading as utf-8

Tags: jquery, ajax, encoding, utf-8

I am experiencing a slight problem with data received through an AJAX call.
I load a JSON file which looks like this:

```
 {"client":[{"FIELD1":"460002",
 {"FIELD1":"460007",
 "FIELD2":"Bilen & Petrol Service",
 "FIELD3":"Gjutjsgatan 1",
 "FIELD4":"",
 "FIELD5":"S-41707 Gorg"},
 {"FIELD1":"460009", [...]
```

My AJAX call looks like this:

```
var clientList = {};
filen = '../json/clientList.json' //The JSON file we want
clientList = (function() {
        var clientList = null;
        $.ajax({
            'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'cache': false,
            'url': filen,
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function(data) {
                console.log('s','clientList',data.responseText,data)
                clientList = data
                }
            });
        return clientList
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(sdsFilter))    
    })();
```

I have checked that the JSON is valid in every way. I've even checked that the serverside script that saves the JSON-files is set to "utf-8". There are nothing in the JSON-files that I can see that causes this provlem.

I load the content of the JSON file into a Select Option using an  $.each script:

```
<select id="valgKunde" class="clientListings">
  <option value="" selected>Choose Customer</option>
</select>

$.each(clientList.client, function(teller, verdi) {
    $('#valgKunde').append('<option value="'+verdi.FIELD1+'">'+verdi.FIELD1+' '+verdi.FIELD2+'</option>')
});
```

So my code works like it should - except for one minor detail.
all special characters shows up like: ""

```
<option value="460007">460007 Car &amp; Petrol Service</option>
<option value="460009">460009 Niclas F &amp; D</option>
```

this: "Bilen & Petrol Service" becomes: "Bilen & Petrol Service" 
this: "Gjutjsgatan 1" becomes "Gjutjsgatan 1"

I have checked through the console.log that the data received is mal-formatted. The JSON-file it self is correct, but the "" shows up randomly it seems, even in places where there are no special characters, like so: "Car & Petrol Service".

so naturally I assume it has something to do with my encoding. I have tried to set the encoding on the html page as well. Any tips, help or nudges in the right direction would be awesome.

Comment: The data that is in the JSON file - was it pasted from something like MS Word or from a webpage, etc? Reason I ask is that I've seen weird random characters show when something has been pasted from Word, webpage, and even from Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: No. the JSON file was generated using a serverside script. The source is a ascii text file which is converted to JSON through server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") and CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") in ASP.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have any other ideas other than trying `text/plain` for your AJAX `contentType`. I've used this same approach to retrieve JSON data many times and have never seen this issue. Reading the [jQuery $.ajax() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), they do state that the charset is always UTF-8 and specifying another charset will not force the browser to change the encoding. My expertise are on the front-end and what you have looks good so hopefully a server-side expert will see this question and have an idea. I've up-voted your question.

Comment: Did you set `.CharSet = "utf-8"` explicitly before opening your `ADODB.Stream` object?